# Parse Javascript Cloud Code Promises

Tags: javascript, parsing, asynchronous

I'd like to query table 1 which contains a column that is a pointer to table 2.

Once I have all the objects from table1 I'd like to get all the pointer values and retrieve the objects from table2, set a value in the table2 objects to a value in table1's objects.

Then return the objects from table2.

Here is what I have which seems to not work.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('myQuery', (req, res) => {
let q1 = new Parse.Query("Table1");
q1.equalTo("userColumn", req.user);
q1.include("column1");
q1.include("accepted");

// Get objects from table 1
var q1Promises = q1.find()
.then(results => {
  q1Promises = results.map(result => {
    return result.get('userColumn')
    .then(user => {
      user.set('accepted', result.get('accepted'));
      return user;
    });
  });
  Promise.all(q1Promises)
  .then(finalResults => {
      res.success(finalResults);
  });
});
});
```

Yes I know I'm not calling .save on the user object and that's because I don't want to save the results.  I just want to access those results client side but I'm not sure how I can return table2 objects along with a value from table1.  So I have a surrogate column in table2 which never really gets set but holds the value from table1 as the relationship is a many to one type of relationship where table1 will have multiple records pointing to table2's objects but each table1 will have a different "accepted" value.

Comment: you're failing to return anything in `.then(results => {` and `results.map(result => {` so are doomed to failure

Comment: I updated the post to return result.get(). I'm not seeing the usual RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/functions/myQuery in my logs though.  The get is successful and I see that.

Comment: oh, I see what you're doing with `q1Promises` now ... seems an odd thing to do ... anyway, if `results.get` returns a promise, does `results.set` expect a promise as the second argument?

Comment: I'm not really sure how else to approach it. I want to return all the users but after I set a column in the user object to have a value from the original result object that holds the pointer to the user.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to return even if I set the results.set('accepted', false); just to hard code the value.

Comment: can you try changing `var q1Promises = q1.find()
.then(results => {
  q1Promises = .....` to `q1.find()
.then(results => {
  var q1Promises = .....`

Comment: Same issue. I'm seeing request for [Post] functions/myQuery then request for [Get] classes/Table1 finally response from [Get] classes/table1

Comment: But no response from functions/myQuery.

Comment: The issue I'm having is I can't call set before the function finishes.  I'm not really sure how else to do it as looping through the mapped results later wouldn't work since I need to set the value on those mapped results to a value that's in the original results being mapped.  After the map call those values are replaced.